# asp.net mvc pager with razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, pager

I working on a project where I am trying to render a pager(from http://en.webdiyer.com/) with razor syntax. Here is code line. I am using asp.net mvc3.

```
@Html.AjaxPager(Model,
    new PagerOptions() {
        PageIndexParameterName = "page",
        CurrentPagerItemWrapperFormatString = "<span class=\"active\">{0}</span>",
        NumericPagerItemWrapperFormatString = "<span>{0}</span>",
        ShowDisabledPagerItems = false,
        NavigationPagerItemWrapperFormatString = "<span>{0}</span>",
        MorePagerItemWrapperFormatString = "<span>{0}</span>",
        CssClass = "pagination-digg",
        NumericPagerItemCount = 7,
        SeparatorHtml = ""
    },
    new AjaxOptions() {
        UpdateTargetId = "dvData",
    })
```

But it doesnt render the html.

Help will be appreciated.

Regards
Parminder

Comment: Your code looks OK. What is the output? Does it simply not do anything? Since this is a third-party library, have you tried contacting the author?

Comment: thanks Slaks and Marcind. it works with webform syntax but not with the razor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. It was not working because, it was returning string whereas MVC3 was excepting MVCHtmlString.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model is a `PagedList<T>` and it is not null or empty, the following should work:

```
@model Webdiyer.WebControls.Mvc.PagedList<Foo>
@Html.AjaxPager(Model, new PagerOptions(), new AjaxOptions())
```

Then try adding options incrementally to see what's the problem.